# How can I add a subscription in Appsync which is invoked by a lambda?

Tags: aws-appsync

I know that subscription in Appsync works with mutation, which means whenever mutation gets invoked, subscription is also invoked which sends the message to all the subscribers.

What I want is that if there is any way, I can basically sends a message to the user directly from lambda using Appsync or any other way in real time? That is, I don't want user to refresh the page.

The use case can be, say, I have a standalone lambda which runs every hour and wants to notify users every hour about something. It is not part of any mutation or query.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a None DataSource to a mutation and send the information required for the subscription to be triggered within the mutation arguments.

for example let's assume you have the following schema

```
type Book {
 bookId: Int
}

input BookInput {
 bookId: Int
}

type mutation {
 triggerBookUpdate(input: BookInput!): Book
}

type subscription {
 onBookUpdate(bookId: Int!): Book
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["triggerBookUpdate"])
}
```

then you attach the None DataSource to the resolver for the TriggerBookUpdate field and provide the following Request Mapping Template

```
#**
Resolvers with None data sources can locally publish events that fire
subscriptions or otherwise transform data without hitting a backend data source.
The value of 'payload' is forwarded to $ctx.result in the response mapping template.
*#
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": $utils.toJson($context.arguments.input)
}
```

and the Response Mapping Template

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

for more information check this [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-none.html)